# Javascript : get current window.open() when parent window was refreshed

Tags: javascript

I want open window but when user refreshed parent location or going to hyperlink, we got last child window and using this code `win_pop.location.replace('http://example.com')` .

for example :

```
var win_pop = window.open(url, 'lastWin', 'width=300px,height=200px,top=1200px,left=2000px');
```

why after refresh parent location child window doesn't working.! before any refresh or going to hyperlink in parent page that working well.

`win_pop.location.replace('http://example.com')` !!

Do you got any best suggest ?

Comment: replace() needs 2 arguments

Comment: @ManosKounelakis — No, it doesn't. You are confusing [location.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) and [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: That's still very unclear to me what is not working and how it should be working... Do you expect the variable `win_pop` to still point to the window opened by the previous page?

Comment: @Kaiido just tell me how can got current `win_pop = window.open()` after refreshing parent href ? you think this is not clear ?

Comment: @Quentin sorry you are right

Comment: Instead of `'lastWin'` use `'_blank'`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You load a page
2. You assign a value to a variable called `win_pop`
3. You load a new page

The lifespan of a JavaScript program running in an instance of a webpage is only as long as that webpage instance exists.

When you have a new page, you have a new JS environment, and the old data is lost.

`win_pop` no longer contains the value you assigned to it.

Much of the time you can store data between pages (e.g. via Local Storage), but that only applies to simple objects, arrays and primitives.

There is no way to preserve the reference to a new window.

---

The only way to achieve that effect would be to avoid reloading the original page. For example, by performing all navigation to "new pages" by using Ajax and manipulating the history with `pushState` and friends.

Answer (score 1):

@Quentin is right about what happens to your js variable, but he seems to have forgotten a little thing:

You can make use of the [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) API and the [`MessageEvent.source`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent/source) property which will point to your popup Window.

So you can start a loop on your popup which will post a message every n-th seconds to `window.opener`.

```
setInterval(function(){
  window.opener.postMessage('foo', '*');
}, delay);
```

Then in all your pages, you will listen for the `message` event, and set your `popup` variable to the `MessageEvent.source` you just retrieved:

```
onmessage = function(evt){
  popup = evt.source;
};
```

And voilà!

#### Here is [a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TmVwykTVE3azO0jDYgTZ?p=preview)